# How can I reset the preview window to the right of the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im not really sure about how my preview window ended up as a different window. I would like to restore it back to the left of the screen, like the default mode. I can't find the way to do it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the gear and click the 'Windowed Mode' again to disable it. It'll go back to the default position.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Easy to see when you are not desesperate! :D